# Windows service network error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have made a windows service and through that service I am doing operations on the database. The machine that I have installed the service is in India and the server is in Singapore. When this service runs I get an error such as

> " A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.) "

I have a connection string such as

```
return "server=122.0.122.222,5222;database=ABCD;user id=abc101;password=xyz";
```

this is in a function that is returning a string. I am catching this string in another string and passing it to the connection object.M I doing anything wrong here.?

But I have tested this service at my house. It works just fine. But when deployed at clients end I get the above error. Any idea why this mite be happening.? Is it related to internet connection but the internet connection is fine. DO I have to give some permissions from my service to make a connection or the IT team of the client should have to give some permissions at their end.?

Please help.
Thanks In advance

Comment: `122.0.122.222,5222` ? not `122.0.122.222.5222` ?

Comment: From the client site check that you can connect to the server on port 5222. An easy way to do it is by telneting to the server: "telnet 122.0.122.222 5222".

Comment: @zey : I did not want to revel the IP address. Its the company policy so I have put just a rough number.